# Find what Normal form a table is in given only functional dependencies

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I am struggling to work out what Normal Form this table would be in, as only functional dependencies are given:

{A,C} -> {B}

{E,C} -> {D}

{A,E} -> {F}

{D} -> {G}

{D} -> {H}

{F} -> {I}

The information given is that the primary key is {A,C,E}.

My working so far is that there are transitive dependencies so the table cannot be in 3NF. However all are fully functional dependencies so the table must be in 2NF.

The next part of the question asks for you to decompose it into 3NF, and this is what I have gotten, however am unsure if it is correct.

Table 1:
{A,E} -> {F}

Table 2:
{C,E} -> {D}

Table 3:
{A,C} -> {B}

Table 4:
{D} -> {G} AND
{D} -> {H}

Table 5:
{F} -> {I}

If someone could confirm if this is correct, or if not give some hints about where I have gone wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 3NF involves *certain* transitive FDs. *Not* all the FDs that hold when your given ones hold are full. 2NF involves *certain* partial FDs. Find, quote & reference definitions of technical terms.

Answer (score 0):

Given the functional dependencies and the key specified, this means that the relation is composed by all the attributes present in the functional dependencies.

Since the (only) candidate key is `{A,C,E}`, and there are dependencies in which a non-prime attribute depends on part of a key (for instance {A,C} -> {B}), the relation is not in Second Normal Form.

For the 3NF, the five tables does not form a correct decomposition, since no relation contains the key. So, for the decomposition to preserve both data and dependencies, you should add the relation R(A, C, E) to the other tables. This is prescribed by the synthesis algorithm of the Third Normal Form.